# What is the command to show if vi is running or not

Tags: bash, command

> Write a single line ‘if-then-else’ command that prints 1 if vi is running and 0 if it does not.

I wrote:

```
if [ $.vi -eq 1 ]; then echo "1"; else echo "0"; fi
```

I don't think that is right. How would I write the command that would print `1` if vi is running?

Comment: What is `$.`  supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bad way, Try like this to check if process (vi) is running

```
if pgrep -x "vi" > /dev/null
then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly sorry but i am not currently in linux. I will test this later and ping you back. Btw you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try ps -C vi and all the other if statements and redirection would be the same.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! "and all the other if statements and redirection would be the same" as what?

Comment: Hi! I was actually referring to @[Wasif Hassan]'s answer. So the only difference from his answer would be changing pgrep -x "vi" to ps -C vi and the rest of the answer would stay the same.